# Installing FTP Client (Library) in C++ Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I have found this library https://github.com/embeddedmz/ftpclient-cpp on GitHub but how to install it on Linux(Ubuntu) is quite obscure.

> You will need CMake to generate a makefile for the static library or
> to build the tests/code coverage program. Also make sure you have
> libcurl and Google Test installed.
>
> You can follow this script
> https://gist.github.com/fideloper/f72997d2e2c9fbe66459 to install
> libcurl.
>
> This tutorial will help you installing properly Google Test on Ubuntu:
> https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/
>
> The CMake script located in the tree will produce Makefiles for the
> creation of the static library and for the unit tests program.
>
> To create a debug static library and a test binary, change directory
> to the one containing the first CMakeLists.txt and :

```
mkdir build    
cd build    
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
make
```

It is not clear to me what "to the one containing the first CMakeLists.txt" refers to. Is it the one in the Gtest? The one in Curl? Or What?

After trying both (the Cmake in Gtest and Curl) I still get the error: "No such file or directory" while trying to #include "FTPClient.h" .

**UPDATE:**

Listing what I am doing:

I did `git clone https://github.com/embeddedmz/ftpclient-cpp.git` then made the build folder, navigate into it, I tried `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug` (this is the literal command I inserted) and I get

> Cmake Error at CmakeLists.txt: 27 (add_subdirectory): add_subdirectory given source "TestFTP" which is not an existing directory

So what is wrong so far?

Comment: They mean the root directory of the project. The one that includes .gitignore and .clang-format.

Comment: "I still get errors while trying to #include "FTPClient.h"" - Please, show (include into the question post) the exact commands you are using and the exact error message you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you build the library, there will be a `libftpclient.a` generated in your build tree.

You can install it to your system as follows:
In this case, copy `libftpclient.a` to `/usr/local/lib` and the two header files in `FTP` to `/usr/local/include`.
You should then be able to include the header files by adding the `-I/usr/local/include` flag and link by adding `-L/usr/local/lib -lftpclient`.

Comment: I did build the Gtest and the Curl but there are no instructions on what I should put in the CMakeLists.txt that is supposed to be in my Project directory. About `libftpclient.a` I cannot find it even if I search it from "/" I think that they should have better specify the installation process for beginners (using Linux from less 2 weeks).

Comment: If your project is also using CMake, it suffices to move the ftpclient-cpp directory under your project's source directory, `include()`'ing the directory, and linking your main target with `target_link_libraries(main ftpclient)`.

Comment: I just downloaded and built the library with `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; cmake --build .` and `libftpclient.a` was generated. I would not call the installation instructions lacking; that is just basic CMake. Don't get discouraged; learning curves are steep but it gets better.

Comment: I did `git clone https...` then made the `build` folder, navigate into it, I tried `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug` (this is the literal command I inserted) and I get >Cmake Error at CmakeLists.txt: 27 (add_subdirectory): add_subdirectory given source "TestFTP" which is not an existing directory.

Comment: You should only do that if you need a debug build. Drop the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug argument.

Comment: Does that TestFTP directory exist? Is your git checkout clean?

Comment: I just tried `cmake ..` but now I still got that same error + this CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (FILE):
  FILE failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):

    /home/my_usr_name/Desktop/SOFTWARE/Ver_0.4/VERSION the weird thing is that I do not even have this "VERSION".

Comment: Before Building there is no TestFTP but it makes one inside build when I do the cmake command. By git checkout do you mean any error when cloning?

Comment: Your *source* directory is the tree you cloned with git clone. The build directory should be created directly under it. You need to run `cmake ..` from within that build directory, such that `..` refers to the source directory. I have no idea how you can get those error messages if you did what you say you're doing.

Comment: Your last comment was what I was looking for! I would upvote it but my rep doesn't allow me to!

Comment: The mandatory argument to `cmake` is the source directory in normal mode. Typically you `cd` to the build directory and point cmake to the source directory, but you can be explicit about both: `cmake -S source-dir -B build-dir && cmake --build build-dir`